# What is this constructor doing?

Tags: c++, qt

**Update:** Thanks for the quick replies and sorry for the duplicate – I didn't know what to search on since I didn't know what that construction is called.

*I've only used very, very simple C++ classes (in working with the Arduino) so excuse me if this question is too basic.*

I'm trying to understand the code snippet below which is from a [Qt BLE example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-pingpong-example.html). I've not seen a constructor like this before. Can someone tell me what it is called (style, etc. so I can look it up), and/or what it is doing?

Obviously it is initializing some instances and some variables but I don't understand why the... (they aren't `parameters`, so what are they?) *"initializers"* are outside of the curly braces.

[pingpong.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-pingpong-pingpong-cpp.html)
[pingpong.h](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-pingpong-pingpong-h.html)

---

```
PingPong::PingPong():
    m_serverInfo(0), socket(0), discoveryAgent(0), interval(5), m_resultLeft(0), m_resultRight(0),
    m_showDialog(false), m_role(0), m_proportionX(0), m_proportionY(0), m_serviceFound(false)
{
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a *member initialization list*. It's necessary for members and bases that can't be default-initialized. But it's also, as here, just a convenient notation.

Note that the order in the list does not influence the actual initialization order.

The members that are initialized, are initialized in declaration order regardless of order in a member initialization list. You might however get a warning if those orders differ. Reason for weasel language: if the constructor that's used to initialize the object doesn't explicitly initialize some *plain old data* member (such as e.g. an `int` member), and that member isn't declared with a default initializer, then that member is just left uninitialized, with an *indeterminate value*.

A full discussion of the relevant details would however be too long to place here.

You need a good C++ textbook, and for that you can look in the SO [C++ Book List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: the order doesn't influence the initialization order, but some compilers (e.g. gcc), complain with a warning "out-of-order" initialization, when full warnings are enabled

Answer (score 2):

It's a way of initializing the members of a class in C++, called *member initializer list*.

Another way (mostly C++11/14/17) can be initializing the members directly in the Header file / Class declaration

Assume:

```
class PingPong
{
  public:
    PingPong();

  private:
    int32_t m_serverInfo{0};
    std::string m_aString{"I am a string"};
};
```

The timer and the `connect()` are used to initialize the QTimer and connect the signal `timeout()` emitted by the timer and connect that event to another function, called `update()` and member of PingPong class

Answer (score 1):

It's [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

> member initializer list specifies the initializers for direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members.
>
> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified. For members that cannot be default-initialized, such as members of reference and const-qualified types, member initializers must be specified. No initialization is performed for anonymous unions or variant members that do not have a member initializer.
>
> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1) If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual base
>   classes are initialized in the order in which they appear in
>   depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations
>   (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
>
> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order
>   as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.
>
> 4) Finally, the body of the constructor is executed